# Discrepancy in lme output and raw data

Tags: regression, lmer

I ran a model with reaction time as my DV and PWI Condition as one of the fixed factors.

I used contr.sum for all fixed factors. I ran the following model to look for differences in reaction time scores across three different IV's (2 levels each).

```
test=lmer(PWI_RT ~ PWI_Condition * Distractor_Condition * 
    Distractor_Language + (1 | Subject) + (1 | Picture_Name),
    data=data1 ,],)
```

The output is as follows:

```
               | Estimate | Std. Error | t value (Intercept)
               | 3605.485 |     77.181 |  46.71
PWI_Condition1 |  109.131 |     30.595 |   3.57
```

The output (deviation coded) shows a positive t value of 2.067 for the PWI condition where Noncognates are coded (-1) and cognates are coded (+1). Hence, I interpret this as cognates take significantly longer to name than non-cognates. However, these results do not match with the raw means. The means for Non-cognates are much longer (in terms of reaction times) than for cognates. 
How can I explain this result?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a coding question. Can you post how you set up & ran your model?